# How to change the Html file referred inside a div on server side using C#?

Tags: c#, html

I have div inside which contactUsFAQ.html is included.

```
    <div id="divContactUsFAQ" runat="server" > 
    <!--#include virtual="../HTML/ContactUsFAQ.html" -->
    </div>
```

I need to include ContactIRP.html file and remove ContactUsFAQ.html on server side.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the `div` as `divContactUsFAQ` from CodeBehind and it has `.InnerHTML` property containing `<!--#include virtual="../HTML/ContactUsFAQ.html" -->` - you can just assign what you need to `.InnerHTML`.

Comment: I am getting error when i try this, div1.innerHTML="<!--#include virtual="../HTML/ContactUsFAQ.html" -->" as it contains double quotes

Comment: what does the error say ? double quotes are supported - you must "escape" them with \

Comment: I used escape character...div1.InnerHtml = "<!--#include virtual=\"../HTML/ContactUsFAQ.htm\" -->"; but the html content is not getting populated in div

Comment: the name of the div is NOT div1 - it is at least according to your html divContactUsFAQ - so you need to do divContactUsFAQ.InnerHtml = "<!--#include virtual=\"../HTML/ContactIRP.html\" -->";

Comment: How did you try it ? where do you execute the code ? in which event ?

Comment: in page_load... divContactUsFAQ.InnerHtml = "<!--#include virtual=\"../HTML/ContactUsFAQar.htm\" -->"; I am able to debug through this line... but the content is not getting displayed in the div

Comment: Are you sure the file ContactUsFAQar.htm exists in that directory ? all files mentioned so far end with .html and not htm